# boto command for describing an Auto Scaling Group?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to write a Python script to list Suspended Processes of a specific Auto Scaling Group in my Amazon Web Services account.

From what I can see, using *boto*, (Not boto3) there is no command to list the specific properties of an auto scaling group.

Can anyone shed a light on this?
Thanks.

Comment: [docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/autoscale.html#boto.ec2.autoscale.AutoScaleConnection.get_all_groups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the little known [`suspended_processes` attribute](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/abb38474ee5124bb571da0c42be67cd27c47094f/boto/ec2/autoscale/group.py#L224) on an autoscale group.

```
import boto
autoscale = boto.connect_autoscale()
group = autoscale.get_all_groups(names=["mygroup"])[0]
group.suspended_processes
```